# How to numerate input

Tags: python, list, input

I wanted to ask how to make the instructions for the user on the screen:

> enter 1 number
> enter 2 number

not just

> enter the numbers

Thank you in advance!

```
numbers  = []
limit = 2

for x in range(limit):
    numbers1 = int(input('enter numbers: '))
    numbers.append(numbers1)

print(numbers)
```

Comment: So you want to know how to format `x` into a string? You can make your example simpler. A single expression. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: it needs normal string formatting - `f-string` or `.format()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as of python 3.6 this is a correct way to do it using f-strings.

```py
for x in range(limit):
    numbers1 = int(input(f'enter {x+1} number: '))
    numbers.append(numbers1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have an index number on each iteration, that is the variable `x`.
You can just print it together with your input text.

```
for x in range(limit):
    number = int(input(f'enter number {x}: '))
    numbers.append(number)
```

If you want so start with 1 instead of 0, you can change your `range`:

```
for x in range(1, limit+1):
    number = int(input(f'enter number {x}: '))
    numbers.append(number)
```